# What is a non-vulgar synonym for this swear word meaning "an enormous amount"?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, colloquial-language, offensive-language

How do I say "*shitload*" or "*shit-ton*" without cursing?

Ideally, I'm looking for a term for casual conversation but without any cursing, the word you can use with kids and teens, or just adults you want to be friendly with without being vulgar.

I found words like "*enormous amount*" but it feels a little too formal and dull (and doesn't work if the word needs "number").

How appropriate is "buttload"? Would it be an acceptable synonym?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes, I think *buttload* is an acceptable, informal substitute, at least in AmE. However, some might still find the usage of *butt* somewhat offensive since some people consider *butt* to be a mild curse word. These people might include parents with very young children. Even so, I think most kids, teens, and adults wouldn't mind. In any case, a few more casual, inoffensive examples include

> 1. [*ton*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ton) - a great quantity :  lot <*ate tons of cookies*> <*has tons of money*> <*a ton of work to do*>
> 2. [*boatload*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boatload) - an indefinitely large number <*a boatload of money*>
> 3. [*load*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/loads)
>
>    10. often **loads** *Informal* A great number or amount: *There were loads of people at the parade.*
> 4. [*lot*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/a+lot)
>
>    1. **a lot** or **lots** *Informal*
>         a. A large extent, amount, or number: *is in a lot of trouble; has lots of friends.*

Comment: +1, esp. for _boatload_. The word _ton_ is a good suggestion as well.

Comment: I also favor *boatload*.

Comment: I also found *shipload*. Is it any good ? Related to *boatload* maybe ?

Comment: @TeleportingGoat I can't say that I've heard it much in the US. Perhaps it is commonly used in other English-speaking countries, but I wouldn't know.

Comment: I've never heard _shipload_ in the UK. It feels like a lazy 'cleaing-up' of shitload to me. _Boatload_ I've heard but it's probably (I'm guessing) unrelated.

Comment: If *buttload* is acceptable, why not go all the way and say *asston*.

Comment: "Boatload" is also the obvious answer that comes to my mind.

Comment: The pattern generalizes to _vehicle_-load of any kind. _Truckload_ and _busload_ also get used.

Comment: I think the objection to *buttload* is not at all around the idea that *butt* might be a curse word, but rather around the poor taste of the evoked imagery about where you keep your items when you have a buttload of them. +1 to *boatload*: boats can be pretty spacious and totally appropriate for carrying cargo.

Answer (score 22):

I like Max's answer, but having lived in NZ for a while (as a non-native English speaker), the first thing that came to mind was [*heaps*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/heaps).

> Noun (*informal*) - a great deal; an enormous amount
>   ⇒ *I've got heaps to tell you.*, ⇒ You have heaps of time.
>
> Adverb (*informal*) - used as intensifier; very much; a great deal
>   ⇒ *He said he was feeling heaps better.*, ⇒ *There's heaps more cake if you want it.*

Comment: I like heap, as it is informal but not vulgar. Additionally, "steaming heap" instantly makes it derogatory.

Comment: Indeed, "heaps" is popular in New Zealand and Australia, although not so common in British or American dialects. The generic intensifier (eg "it's heaps good!") is used in Australia but uncommon in New Zealand.

Answer (score 17):

The polite version of shitload is 'shedload' or 'shedloads'. Whether 'buttload' is acceptable or not probably depends where you are - it wouldn't be acceptable in front of children in the UK, or in BrE. I can't say I find it that pleasant either, and I'm not a child...

Comment: Just FYI to readers: This is not common at all in the US

Comment: @DoritoStyle not sure if you mean shedload is uncommon or buttload is uncommon in the US, but just as a  point of interest, the first time I heard this expression around 20 years ago in the UK it started out as'shedload' and changed to shitload after probably about 3 years.

Comment: Good point, I was referring to "shedload(s)"

Comment: Sounds like a [minced oath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minced_oath) of `shitload` rather than a true alternative. After all, aren't most sheds rather small?

Comment: @ArtB not necessarily, sheds can be big enough to serve as aircraft hangars or engine houses, but even an ordinary shed is likely bigger than your average pile of s...t, so why use s...t  at all, there's no reason to assume your average pile would be large anyway, its just because its a mild curse word that it's used

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that shedload came first & was corrupted.

Comment: @Tetsujin I doubt that’s the case. The OED attests _shitload_ from 1954, and _shedload_ only from 1992.

Comment: Ah, OK, then euphemism - my bad, I didn't research

Answer (score 9):

Humans have been producing social meaning from language nearly as long as we've been producing excremental material from nutrition.

We might not need many mental steps to move from *buttload* to *shitload* and, from that juncture, produce a picture, feeling or perception that some would find vulgar, inappropriate for some situations, or with which we might otherwise sit unpleasantly.

*Butt,* in and of itself, for example in *(someone/something is) a pain in the butt* or *give (someone) a kick in the butt* seems relatively less likely to offend on the sensabilities of most native English speakers than might *a buttload,* probably because reactive to *butt,* we'd expect even the more imaginative among us to conjure up an image of the prototypical fleshy globes so visually similar to peaches (a perfectly wholesome fruit), and often associated with expression of cuteness, humor, and a supple vitality. If any other sense would be generally activated consequent to such a crack, anecdotal evidence (introspective case-study method) suggests it is likely to be through the aural perceptive modality, such as the good-natured *thwack* emanating from a locker room in which happy and well-paid athletes demonstrate charming and harmless fraternal bonding via various playful and congratulatory smacking and patting maneuvers, or the popular songs of Jennifer Lopez (a 1997 Golden Globe nominee).

With *buttload,* on the other hand, fundamental psycholinguistic principles plainly suggest cognitive focus would often receive a dump of emotionally charged information squatly bound to the *load* component of the term, suggesting--even forcing--reactivity to foulness or an intolerable reek, funk, or dirtiness that may be more likely to cause a negative reaction in some than the use of the term *butt* in itself.

The term *load,* as betrayed by its common transition from noun to verb, represents potential action, a promise of release which most may yearn for, at least symbolically as a projected residue of past experiences with struggles against letting go, but which few truly wish to experience intimately as a product of a constructed other.

There are a shitload of terms and phrases to convey the idea of a large amount. Many people find vulgar terms, profanity, sex-related terms, or potty talk useful because they often carry a striking intensity, or deliver a powerful emphasizing effect, which may be why you chose *shitload* as a starting point for your question rather than merely asking for strong or emphatic terms that mean a large quantity.

You might use *mountains* of (substance), or *millions* of (objects) effectively, depending on tone of voice, other contextual factors, and exactly what you might be referring to.

If you supplied a particular example, or specified the question further, we may be better able to supply what you're looking for.

Meanwhile, searches in dictionaries and thesauruses for synonyms for simple terms like *many, myriad, large, massive, huge, ton,* etc., should provide a range of options. If none seem to do the trick, you might try editing your question and trying to explain what you want to express that such alternatives don't seem to accomplish.

Comment: "Butt" may be less offensive than shit but it is still pretty offensive, or at least considered impolite by plenty of English speakers. If you're trying to avoid offence by avoiding *shitload*, then I would suggest avoiding *buttload* as well.

Comment: This answers seems far too verbose.

Comment: It is indeed a butt-full.

Comment: I like how you sprinkling in the harmless words "dump" and "squat" helps evoke the intended mental image

Comment: I love how the answer managed to sound like a headmaster's lecture, yet still made me laugh like Beavis & Butthead at "such a crack". I do hope it was intentional.

Answer (score 9):

Not sure why it was removed in later revisions, but an older version of [Wikipedia's list of Indefinite and fictitious numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Indefinite_and_fictitious_numbers&oldid=467119284#General_placeholder_names) had some real gems:

- buckets
- couple-few
- "forty-leven"
- oodles
- scads
- umpteen
- lots of made-up words ending in "-illion", like *gazillion* and *bazillion*

Probably the most *direct* replacement for "shitload/shitton" would be "metric load/metric ton".

Comment: Umpteen is a good one. I imagine that it is chiefly British though.

Comment: "bags" in Australia.

Comment: @Bladorthin - I hear _umpteen_ relatively often here in the US.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey, not at all.  I'm born & bred in the Northeastern U.S.  We say "umpteen" or even "umpteen million", or "umpteen bazillion."

Answer (score 6):

Crap is usually considered a milder equivalent to shit. So I would go with crap load or crap ton.

Comment: Really, "it's a ton of crap" *not* "crap ton"

Comment: @Mari-LouA "crap ton" is used as well (at least in AmE) - "OMG that is a *crap ton* of work. I think I'll call in sick today." While I think this answer could use a little more explanation and maybe an example sentence, it's not wrong.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I hear "crap ton" all the time.

Comment: @Mari-LouA And now that I think about it "ton of crap" and "crap ton" mean different things. A ton of crap is a comment on the quality as well as the amount (you wouldn't use it for a lot of a good thing). "I had to deal with *a ton of crap* today because you called in sick." versus "I ate a crap ton of crab at the all-you-can-eat buffet last night because it was so good."

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm going to agree with the others.  It's *very* slangy but it's fine to say "crap-ton", as well as other creative variations like "a metric fuck-load".  People come up with new expressions like this all the time.  :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit OK, but *crap*, *ton of crap*, and *crap ton*  are still "vulgar" and offensive, they were in my day, you wouldn't say it to the Queen's face, would you?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: No, I wholly agree this is not a good answer to the question. Just not for the reason originally given.

Comment: I also DV because it was poor and went against the OP's request, "a ton of crap" might have been referring to the erm.. answer itself. No offence, Michael.

Comment: You can't say "shit" on Stack Exchange. You have to substitute it with the word *crap* which suffices for almost every instance imaginable or compound word made thereof.

Comment: @Mari Only if the Queen said it first, as in *We have a crap-ton of shitty appointments today, and We have a goddamned cold.*

Answer (score 6):

The best direct non-vulgar synonym (as per question title) for "a **shitload**" would be "an **obscene amount**", meaning:

> so large an amount or size as to be very shocking or unfair.

Asker stated (emphasis mine):

> I found words like "enormous **amount**" but it feels a little too formal and dull (and doesn't work if the word needs **"number"**).

As such, this answer doesn't really fulfill all of asker's requirements, but in my opinion "an obscene amount" does carry the intended meaning, because "obscene" is linked to derogatory terms.

Comment: This is actually a great answer; appears under-appreciated.  It actually carries the exact intended meaning without messing around with euphemisms or ultra-formal words like "plethora."  The answer could be improved with a few examples: "He makes an obscene amount of money";  "After my vacation I had an obscene amount of emails to handle."

Answer (score 3):

You might also consider using "metric ton" if you want to be a tiny bit more formal. The derivation is based on the metric system, and the idea that, purely in terms of the metric ton vs the US (short) ton, then a metric ton is heavier (2,204.6 pounds) than a short ton (2000lb) which gives us the use of "metric"as an intensifier.

Comment: The problem with "ton" (with or without the word "metric" is depending on the context someone may take it too literally.

Comment: @PeterGreen I doubt there would be much confusion in most of the contexts it would be used. (That kid has a metric ton of angst!) I think this is a nice, if US-centric, addition to the choices and it has an explanation of why it is used, which I appreciate.

Comment: Amusingly, I'm British. Not sure why I use it or where I picked it up from.

Comment: @Wenlocke: I picked up "metric <rude word>ton" from programming chatrooms on IRC, I think. Is it possible you also got it from Americans on the internet?

Comment: We use it in Canada too despite using metric tonnes, because it's funny, and nearly always unambiguously so: Saying a *metric* tonne/ton is nearly always redundant in context, and when talking about a “metric ton” of something that really *shouldn't* be measured in tons, it's obviously an intensifier. E.g.: “We have a metric tonne of complaints about the new design.” It doesn't have quite the same punch as *shit-tonne*, but it slides in smoothly as a replacement that does the same job. (And of course, you can also have a *metric shit-tonne*, for extra intesification.)

Answer (score 3):

As some of the earlier answers/comments suggested, "shipload" works wonders at getting as close to the same shock value as cursing.

Since having kids I started adopting something similar to replace many of my curse words with logical alternatives. If you really want to emphasize it and get some heads turning/thinking/chuckling, prepend it with "frigate" (a type of ship). My favorite phrase in this context:
"That's a frigate shipload of *context* you've got there!"

Answer (score 3):

In Northern California, one might substitute the word **hella** for this purpose.

Definition:

> Hella: a large amount or number of.

Example:

> "We found **hella** Pokemon in the Mission"

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hella

This word has been proposed to be the numeric prefix for figures followed by 27 zeros (the likes of "kilo" and "giga").  Should this be accepted by the international scientific community, I think it might attain more common use.

[http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/science/science-news](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/science/science-news/7352204/Hella-number-scientists-call-for-new-word-for-1000000000000000000000000000.html)

Comment: This answer is hella cool.

Comment: I've only ever heard this used as an adverb, as in @RobertColumbia's "hella cool."  It sounds very very odd when used as an adjective and should be regarded as not merely informal usage but straight-up *slang,* not at all guaranteed to be understood.

Answer (score 3):

Just substitute, “shit” with “stuff” and rejigger the concept a bit and you can easily use it with pretty much any audience.

**Piles of Stuff**

- “Did you see that new discount store that opened? They have piles of stuff!”
- “The new boss gave me piles of stuff to do; I’m up to my neck.”
- “Just when I think I’m done, new piles of stuff show up seemingly out of nowhere.”

Answer (score 2):

To me, the most obvious, and completely inoffensive, option is "bunch".

As in, "I have a bunch of errands to run today" or "I bought a bunch of food at the store".

From Merriam-Webster:

> a :  a number of things of the same kind *a bunch of grapes*
>   b :  group *a bunch of friends*
>   c :  a considerable amount : lot *a bunch of money*

Any option that ends in 'load' is probably going to be somewhat offensive. A 'buttload' conjures up an image of a butt literally filled with the thing. A "buttload of grapes" is a literally the number of grapes needed to fill a butt. That's not super pleasant.

Answer (score 2):

A word I have used is 
**mega-ton** 
from nuclear explosions but it looks like I made it up as slang.
Maybe you could use 
**mega-pile**.

I have heard words like **BFP** 
for big frigging pile but that may be vulgar as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the adjective *galore*.

> adjective
>
> :  abundant, plentiful —used postpositively

Source: [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/galore)

This is an Irish (Gaelige)-derived term that is used as a [postpositive adjective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective). It isn't terribly formal, but it is not vulgar and is great if you want to impart a little Celtic or quasi-Celtic flavor to your speech.

> *food and drink galore*.
>
> 1660-70; < Irish go leor enough, plenty ( Scots Gaelic gu leòr, leòir), equivalent to go, particle forming predicative adjectives and adverbs + leór enough ( Old Irish lour)

Source: [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/galore)

Answer (score 2):

A USAian who recalls old tv series, or who wants to evoke such a memory, could use "mass quantities".  That would probably trigger for anyone over 50, and possibly for anyone over 40 (re-runs).

For my part, I use the German word "Haufe" (heap).  Even though non-speakers of German probably won't know the word, they'll nevertheless get the idea from the context.

Answer (score 2):

How about [ginormous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ginormous) (amount) or [humongous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/humongous) (amount)?

*Ginormous* is less formal than *enormous* and has a more playful tone. It also implies a really large amount (ie. combination of *gigantic* and *enormous*).

> How appropriate is "buttload"?

Personally I don't like "cute" substitutions for swear words. If you are going to swear *go ahead and swear*. Don't substitute some other word that the listener then has to substitute back in their minds.

Answer (score 2):

You can say "___ ***up the wazoo***". Apparently "wazoo" here is a euphemism for the butt. I don't think this expression would be likely to be perceived as offensive, although apparently at least some people think of it as "vulgar". Mark Liberman gives more explanation in a Language Log post: [The Road to Wazoo](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=30325)

Some definitions:

- > **out/up the wazoo**: 
  > *US informal* :  in large amounts   ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/up%20the%20wazoo))
- > **up the wazoo**, to an extreme degree or in great abundance:
  >   *She's got problems up the wazoo.* ([Dictionary.com Unabridged](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/up--the--wazoo), Random House)
- > **up (or out) the wazoo**
  >   
  > *US informal* 
  >   
  > Very much; in great quantity; to a great degree.
  >   
  > *‘he's insured out the wazoo’
  >   
  > ‘Jack and I have got work up the wazoo already’* ([Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/up_(or_out)_the_wazoo))

Answer (score 1):

Must be a thousand ways (huge number?) to answer this.  The most obvious is "boatload", retaining the original structure and connotation (IMO) without the vulgarity.  I'm unsure why "enormous amount" seems too formal to you but I understand too well the "dumbing down" of our language.

Please don't use "buttload", "crapload", "BFP", etc. OK, so I'm an old fogey and set in my ways. It don't make me wrong.